# I want to check whether an integer is unique inside an array using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

//Remove Method

```
public static int[] remove(int[]a){
int [] x = new int[a.length - 1];

for(int i = 1; i <= x.length; i++) {
    x[i-1] = a[i];  
}

return x;}
```

IsUniqueMethod to check uniqueness of Passed int

```
public static boolean isUnique(int []x, int n) {
if(x.length == 1) { 
    return true;}
else {
    
    if(x[0] != n) {
        return isUnique(remove(x), n);
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
    
}
```

}

How could I check the uniqueness?

Comment: How can you check uniqueness by removing first elements?

Comment: You need to use `return isUnique(remove(x), n);` Other than that I surely hope that's an assignment of sorts and not something you are actually going to use somewhere. It's... horrendously complicated and inefficient.

Comment: The result of your recursive call to isUnique is not returned. And please indent properly, it makes code much more readable.

Comment: @Ben Here's the assignment !   
Write a recursive method isUnique that takes an integer n and an array of integers as a parameter and returns a boolean value indicating whether or not n is unique in the array (true for yes, false for no).
A value in an array is considered to be unique if it appears only once in the array. For example, if a variable called list stores the following values:
int[] list = {4, 7, 2, 3, 9, 12, -47, -19, 308, 3, 74};
isUnique(list,9) ---> true
isUnique(list,3) ---> false
isUnique(list,0) ---> false
You are not allowed to use any static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never give you the isUnique() output that you are looking for. Even if somehow you make it past the ArrayIndexOutOfBound, the code you have written is so inefficient that the JIT will be called every single time you pass a method parameter inside a recursive call.

Try this instead

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unique {

     private static Scanner sc;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         //Taking length of the array from the user
         System.out.println("Enter the length of the desired array : ");
         int length = sc.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Please enter the values of the array");
         ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         //Entering the values into the arrayList
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             al.add(sc.nextInt());
         }

         System.out.println("Enter a number you wish to check : ");
         int checkNumber = sc.nextInt();

         //Using the built-in method indexOf() to check the occurance of the entered number and return its index if present, else returns -1
         System.out.println(al.indexOf(checkNumber)>=0?"The entered number is present in the array":"The entered number is not present in the array");

     }}
```